# read json array on mysql query

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, json-extract

I know about the possiblity of duplicity of question but i don't found anything to help me on my situation about it.

I have this json on my mysql column:

```
[
  {
    "ddi": "55",
    "routing_id": "7",
    "price": {
      "mt": 0.0285,
      "mo": 0.0285
    }
  },
  {
    "ddi": "598",
    "routing_id": "10",
    "price": {
      "mt": 0.06,
      "mo": 0.06
    }
  }
]
```

When i do the following query:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(my_column,'$[*].ddi') as ddi FROM my_table
```

I get the result:

```
["55", "598"]
```

My question is:
There is a way to return this data on rows instead a json array?
Like:

```
Ddi
55
598
```

Comment: why you need data in this format? After getting json data you can manipulate that data according to your need

Comment: Hi @AbuSufian maybe i'm being wrong about the way to do it but with this data i pretend make a INNER JOIN" on another table to get the country name by ddi. I'm trying to do this by one single query instead of manipulate the json and do another query.

Comment: If you need to access individual fields within your JSON for joins, it's a red flag for database design. You should structure the data in a normalized fashion instead of using JSON.

Comment: @BillKarwin hmm ok... based on your comment, the better way to do this is manipulate the json and then make a new one query to achieve my intentions right?

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean **do not use JSON to store structured data** if you want to query individual elements later. Use normal columns and rows. In this case, you need a table with one row per `ddi` and another table with one row per price for each `ddi`. Using JSON is convenient for storing a complex nested structure of data in one step, but your question is an example of where storing data in JSON instead of in normal form makes it much _harder_ to query later.

Comment: @BillKarwin thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `JSON_TABLE` for the same

```
SELECT get_ddi.* 
FROM my_table, 
     JSON_TABLE(my_column, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                my_column VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.ddi')
     ) get_ddi;
```

```
**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
      `id` SERIAL,
      `my_column` JSON
    );
    
    INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `my_column`)
    VALUES
      (1, '[
      {
        "ddi": "55",
        "routing_id": "7",
        "price": {
          "mt": 0.0285,
          "mo": 0.0285
        }
      },
      {
        "ddi": "598",
        "routing_id": "10",
        "price": {
          "mt": 0.06,
          "mo": 0.06
        }
      }
    ]');

**Query #1**

    SELECT get_ddi.* 
    FROM my_table, 
         JSON_TABLE(my_column, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                    my_column VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.ddi')
         ) get_ddi;

**Output**

| my_column |
| --------- |
| 55        |
| 598       |
```

As per @Guilherme Mascarenhas comments below, the solution needed was for MariaDb. As of version 10.2.31, `JSON_TABLE` function doesn't exist for MariaDB.
A hacky solution could be to use appropriate mariadb sequence table(Depending on the number of rows). JSON_UNQUOTE removes the quote from the extracted value. `seq` is used as index to get the specified `ddi` value from the array.

```
SELECT 
    JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(t.my_column, CONCAT('$[', seq_0_to_100.seq, '].ddi'))) AS getddi
FROM my_table t
JOIN seq_0_to_100
HAVING getddi IS NOT NULL;

**Output**

| my_column |
| --------- |
| 55        |
| 598       |
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(my_column, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                     my_column VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.' at line 3 0.156 sec

I'm using: Mysql MariaDB Version 10.2.31

Comment: You didn't tag or mention MariaDB in your question. The above mentioned solution works for  MySQL v8.0 . MariaDB does not have a JSON_TABLE function. Will update the post for MariaDB.

Comment: @ Guilherme Mascarenhas :Did the solution for MariaDb work for you?

Comment: works like a charm! I didn't know the sequence function on MariaDB...
For anyone who want more details about it > https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/

Answer (score 1):

Json Details:

```
"customers": [
    {
        "email": "kar@mailinator.com",
        "fullName": "Kar**",
        "mobilePhone": "63968**"
    },{
        "email": "kar1@mailinator.com",
        "fullName": "Kar1**",
        "mobilePhone": "639681**"
    }

]
```

Assume in the table there are 10 rows having a attributes as json colum and having above data in it. I like to get all mobilePhone value from each rows customers json array in a table manner:

```
SELECT mobilePhone.* 
FROM mh_customer_targets , 
     JSON_TABLE(attributes, '$.customers[*]' COLUMNS (
                attributes VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.mobilePhone')
     ) mobilePhone
```

Result:

```
attributes
63968**
639681**
```

Credits: [Rahul Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13675913/rahul-singh)